# formated numbers on DataGridView not as I need

Tags: c#, winforms

I have in my C# WinForm DataGridView that holds numbers

the problem is that:

```
0.5  -->  shows -->  .5     and

-45 -->  shows -->  45-
```

**in my DataGridView the  RightToLeft = yes**  (i must have this)

how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property of a DataGridViewCellStyle.
For example (supposing your first colum's name is "Value")

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Value"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.0";
```

The Format property takes strings 'formats' well explained in these articles on MSDN

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8)
[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k)

Comment: thanks for the help, OK now i see 0.5 but still see 56- instead of -56 
in my DataGridView the RightToLeft = yes (i must have this)

Comment: @Gali sorry, but I can't really help here. The RightToLeft changes the display of the numbers and I think you should handle the CellPainting event as discussed [in this post](http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/NET-WinForms-Controls/33821200/setting-righttoleft-property-for-columns-in-a-datagridview.aspx)

Comment: Have you looked at the link in my previous comment? There is a sample of this event handling

Answer (score 0):

See the `formatting Types & custom numeric format strings` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

& `How to format data` in DataGridView here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

double value = .5; 
var display = value.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));